# How to call this method in C# to return data from WS

Tags: c#

I'm begginer with c#. I would like to develop a simple application that retrieve data from WS. I have this method below but I don't know how to call it in the main method in order to return a value from WS.

```
public static P6WSStubs.Ws.P6.WBS.WBS[] ReadWbs(string WbsIdListFilter)
    {
        PrimaveraService.HostName = "xxx.xx.xxx.xxx";
        PrimaveraService.Port = "8206";
        PrimaveraService.HTTP = "http://";
        WBSFieldType[] wbsFieldTypeArray = new WBSFieldType[17] { WBSFieldType.ObjectId, WBSFieldType.Code, WBSFieldType.Name, WBSFieldType.ProjectObjectId, WBSFieldType.ParentObjectId, WBSFieldType.SummaryPlannedStartDate, WBSFieldType.SummaryPlannedFinishDate, WBSFieldType.SummaryActualStartDate, WBSFieldType.SummaryActualFinishDate, WBSFieldType.SummaryDurationPercentComplete, WBSFieldType.SummaryUnitsPercentComplete, WBSFieldType.SummaryPerformancePercentCompleteByCost, WBSFieldType.SummaryRemainingTotalCost, WBSFieldType.SummaryEarnedValueByCost, WBSFieldType.SummaryPlannedCost, WBSFieldType.SummaryBudgetAtCompletionByCost, WBSFieldType.SummaryEstimateAtCompletionByCost };
        ReadWBS ReadWBS1 = new ReadWBS();
        ReadWBS1.Field = wbsFieldTypeArray;
        ReadWBS1.Filter = "ObjectId IN (" + WbsIdListFilter + ")";
        WBSService wbsService = new WBSService();
        wbsService.Url = HTTP + HostName + ":" + Port + "/p6ws/services/WBSService";
        wbsService.Timeout = 6000000;
        wbsService.CookieContainer = PrimaveraService.cookieContainer;
        return wbsService.ReadWBS(ReadWBS1);

    }
```

How should i call this method in order to receive a value from WS?
Sorry for this stupid question..

Comment: Something like `P6WSStubs.Ws.P6.WBS.WBS[] result = ReadWbs("whateverYourFilterValuesAre");`

Comment: Many thanks! But If I want to pop up a message box with the name of the WBS, can you please give me a hint?

Comment: Well you can easily google how to display a message box already. And we can't see the content of your `result` array so we don't know where within it the name is stored (in order to fetch it and send it to the messagebox). So the first part we don't need to help you with, and the second part we can't help you with (without seeing further information)

Comment: where I can see :  the content of my result array in order to knowwithin it the name is stored ?

Comment: I want to take information and write them in excel

Comment: pause your code using a breakpoint in the visual studio debugger and hover over the `result` variable, and then you can inspect the contents of the variable and see its structure.

Comment: Many thanks again!! I was using the debuging but not on the result :) Thx again!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that both your ReadWbs and Main method are in the same class, in which case your code should look something like the following (the order of the methods may be different, that doesn't matter):

```
public static P6WSStubs.Ws.P6.WBS.WBS[] ReadWbs(string WbsIdListFilter)
{
   //Same as above
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string wbsIdListFilter = "<Your Filter Here>";
    P6WSStubs.Ws.P6.WBS.WBS[] result = ReadWbs(wbsIdListFilter);
    //...
}
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks it seems is work. But If I want to pop up a message box with the name of the WBS, can you please give me a hint?

Comment: You can use System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show, assuming you are writing a Windows Forms application. If you are writing a console application (more likely if you are directly referencing Main), then use Console.WriteLine(). Stack overflow isn't really oriented towards beginner tutorials, you'd be much better off learning some C# programming basics from elsewhere on the internet. You'll struggle to make much progress if you keep asking questions on here.

Comment: thanks for answer. I knew that I must use the messagebox.show command..but I didn't know that I must use the debug on the result. I used in on the method. Thanks again.